# How to get bssid of my hotspot in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create a flutter app, in which when I start my hotspot i want its bssid to be stored in my app and displayed.
The bssid displayed on my phone  should be the same if someone  connects to my  hotspot, the bssid displayed on wifi on their device.

I have tried various packages(wifiiot,network info, etc) but i am just able to display the bssid of the wifi that are available to me and cant access the bssid of my own hotspot.

Help me along with the code to print own device hotspots's bssid.